# react-native-ble-plx disconnects from BLE device whenever I use navigation.navigate()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-context, react-native-ble-plx

I am using React Native context to pass data from a simple react-native-ble-plx script to different screens in my app. I'm using react-native-navigation for these screens. Whenever I call navigation.navigate(), I successfully navigate to another screen, but I no longer have bluetooth communication, even if I navigate back to the original screen. How do I keep sending data from my BLE context to the different screens in my app, without disconnecting?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is happening because you are handling/monitoring the connection on the page instead of doing it via a service. Separating BLE functionality from the UI should fix this issue. Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [How to maintain bluetooth connection on page navigation](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/issues/622)
- [I cannot maintain Bluetooth connection when navigating to another screen](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/issues/751)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a "solution" but I solved this problem by removing React Navigation from my project, and just handling the screens manually like this:

```
<View>
  {showScreen1 && <View></View>} 
  {showScreen2 && <View></View>}
</View>
```